# How to add a subquery to ANY operator in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below query works well, it returns all the receipts which are composed of ingredients which can be found at home. The ingredients which are at home are: `yiest`, `oil`, `flour`, `salt`, `water`:

```
SELECT *
FROM receipts 
WHERE true = ALL(
    SELECT name ~~* ANY('{%yeast%, %Oil%, %Flour%, %salt%, %water}') 
    FROM ingredients 
    WHERE ingredients.receipt_id = receipts.id
)
```

It returns 24 results out of 11000.

The below query returns all the ingredients which can be found at home:

```
SELECT string_agg('%' || name || '%', ', ') 
FROM home_ingredients 
LIMIT 1
```

returns: '%yeast%, %oil%, %flour%, %water%, %salt%'

Then what I want is to compose the 2 queries into 1 single query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM receipts 
WHERE true = ALL(
    SELECT name ~~* ANY(SELECT string_agg('%' || name || '%', ', ') 
    FROM home_ingredients LIMIT 1) 
    FROM ingredients 
    WHERE ingredients.receipt_id = receipts.id
)
```

I also tried with this:

```
SELECT '{'|| string_agg('%' || name || '%', ', ') || '}' 
FROM home_ingredients
```

Both returning 0.

Any hints helping me to compose the 2 queries into 1 single query would be very appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `with cte` is there to the total Ingredient found at home_ingredients for each receipt, then this total should match the total number of ingredients found at the receipt.

```
with cte as (
  select r.*, s.totalIngrFound
  from receipts r
  inner join (
    SELECT r.id, count(1) as totalIngrFound
    FROM receipts r
    INNER JOIN ingredients i ON i.receipt_id = r.id
    INNER JOIN home_ingredients hi on i.name like concat('%',hi.name,'%')
    group by r.id
  ) as s on s.id = r.id  
)
select c.id, c.name
from cte c
inner join (
  select receipt_id, count(1) as totalIngr
  from ingredients
  group by receipt_id
) as s on s.receipt_id = c.id and s.totalIngr = c.totalIngrFound;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lH9RHILC)

Comment: I am afraid that this is not working, because the query returns those recipes where at least one of the ingredients can be found at home.  But I want those recipes where all the ingredients are found at home. I executed this query on my data and it returned similar amount of data like my query did with replacing the "ALL" operator to "ANY". I want those recipes returned where ALL the ingredients belonging to the recipe can be found at home.

Comment: Can you check my last update

Comment: It is a brilliant idea, however a super clear version of it is to create 2 relations by WITH, one for the total ingredients found and other for the total ingredients needed, then join and compare them in the "business query" at the end. I also changed to ILIKE to have case insensitive match

Answer (score 0):

demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/u3MiQpoC
I just use regex pattern matching, instead of ilike.
setup.

```
CREATE TABLE receipts (
    receipt_id int,
    name text
);
INSERT INTO receipts (receipt_id, name)
    VALUES (1, 'yeast'),(1, 'oil'),(1,'flour'),(1, 'salt'),(1,'water');
INSERT INTO receipts (receipt_id, name)
    VALUES (2, 'yeast2'),(2, 'oil2'),(2,'flou__r'),(2, 'salt2'),(2,'water2');
INSERT INTO receipts (receipt_id, name)
    VALUES (1, 'John''s Hamburger'),(2, 'John''s Hamburger2');

CREATE TABLE ingredients (
    receipt_id int,
    name text
);
INSERT INTO ingredients (receipt_id)
    VALUES (1),(2),(7);
CREATE TABLE home_ingredients (
    home_ingredients_id int,
    name text
);
INSERT INTO home_ingredients (home_ingredients_id, name)
    VALUES (1, 'flour');
```

query:

```
with cte(name) as
(
SELECT * from( values('yeast'),('oil'), ('salt'), ('water')) s
union all
(SELECT
    hi.name
FROM
    home_ingredients hi
ORDER BY
    1
LIMIT 1)
)
SELECT sub.* from
(
    SELECT sub.*
        ,count(*) over(partition by receipt_id) as count
    from
    (
    SELECT
        r.*
    FROM
        receipts r
    WHERE
        EXISTS (
            SELECT
            FROM
                ingredients i
            WHERE
                i.receipt_id = r.receipt_id)
    ) sub
    left join cte c on sub.name ~* c.name
    where c.name is not null
) sub
where count = 5;
```

Comment: Also this is not good:     `AND r.name ~* ANY ((` because I want to "those receipts where all the ingredients belonging to the receips can be found at home" and I did that by matching the ingredients name with the home ingredient name. Not receipt name like You did

Comment: The SELECT hi.name FROM home_ingredients hi ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1 returns flour for me. However I want an array coming from the db.

Comment: Also the good test data would be like:
Recipe(name: "John's Hamburger", id:1), Ingredient(name: "salt", receipt_id: 1), Ingredient(name: "wheat", receipt_id: 1), Ingredient(name: "yeast", receipt_id: 1), Ingredient(name: "meat", receipt_id: 1)
Hope that helps